# invalid date in bootstrap datetimepicker + momemtjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker with momentjs. I am getting invalid date during form initialization **only in IE**. Below is my datetime picker initilization code. Below is the attached image. Date is selected properly, but a red color 'x'(glyphicon-remove) is disaplyed. I am using IE 11.

```
<input id="tbmatdeadline" class="form-control" style="width:150px;"  /> 

 $('#tbmatdeadline').datetimepicker({
                minDate: moment()
               ,format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
               ,locale : 'de-DE'
            });
```

[Image showing invalid date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4FJo.png)

Thanks

Comment: Your image is showing exactly what you specified in your code. Day- 12th, Month - 03, Year - 2018.

Comment: I am talking about the red color 'x'

Comment: Can you post your $('#tbmatdeadline') control's code? This is going to be a CSS issue, likely a bit of css IE doesn't support. The version of IE would be useful to know as well.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Is there more to that control group? Typically bootstrap has a surrounding div and a span that add styling to that control.

Comment: There is nothing more to that group. Is there someway to find why the "X" is appearing?

Comment: It's coming from bootstrap. the red outline and the "X" are applied by bootstrap when validation fails on a field. I guess if you don't need to validate the form, you could just add the 'novalidate' tag on your input.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I found the problem, I was formatting the date and it caused the problem.